# Karate V1.0.1 * configure charset = null is not working

Tags: karate

I tried to upgrade from V 0.9.6 to V 1.0.1 but my tests started failing then I realised that setting charset = null when saving a file was been ignored and charset=UTF-8 was added to the file which causes my test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely it is a bug. Look, [we spent *months* asking users to try RC versions](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1349603552478461953).

So now, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - so that we can fix it - because all our existing test-suites pass.

And I also suggest you look at contributing code or providing as much help as possible to replicate and troubleshoot this - else you can expect to remain on the old version for some time.